# Apache 403 only appears on localhost, other hostnames are fine

Tags: apache, localhost, wamp, wampserver

On an installation of Apache via WAMPserver, `http.conf` is set to

```
<Directory "c:/WAMP/www/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

The `hosts` file is set to

```
127.0.0.1       awesomedudes
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

However, only `http://awesomedudes` goes to `c:/WAMP/www` correctly. `http://localhost` instead returns the following:

```
403 Forbidden

You don't have permission to access / on this server.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it! The WAMP Server is running on Windows 8, which uses IPv6 by default. When specifying hostnames via `hosts`, IPv4 is used and connects to 127.0.0.1 correctly. However, Windows 8 resolves `localhost` via IPv6, which Apache then sees as coming in from the IPv6 localhost at `::1`.

Adding the following to `httpd.conf` resolved the issue (The extra line before `Allow from ::1` is there to keep the line from being rewritten by WAMPserver's "Put Online" function):

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1

Allow from ::1
```